# App_Offline.htm to run in schedule task

Tags: asp.net, app-offline.htm

I have a website that have a scheduler (run in schedule task) that runs everyday at 12am and it takes 15mins to finish. I need to take down the website while the scheduler is running. I know that asp.net have the app_offline.htm, I would like to ask if anyone tried to use the idea of app_offline will automatically created in the website so if the scheduler runs at 12am, the system is automatically gives the user that the system is under maintenance. Then after the scheduler is done, the app_offile is automatically removed so that the system will now automatically up and can now use by the user.

Or any idea how can I have a similar solution for the automatic message for the user that the website is under maintenance when the scheduler starts to run and after finish, the website will be up automatically.

any help.. Thanks in advance!

enaj